# не работает Php exec

Tags: php

Пытаюсь выполнить команды например:

```
shell_exec('echo hi');
exec('echo hi');
system('echo hi');
```

но когда в него пишу допустим скрипт ноды:

`exec('node -v');`

во всех трех вариантах не работает! хотя тут же пишу это в консоли и срабатывает, как такое может быть?

Comment: Попробуйте двойные кавычки

Comment: плевать он хотеЛ, не выполняет и все

Comment: у `exec` есть ещё два аргумента. используйте их, это поможет понять причину. там наверняка есть ненулевой код ответа и сами данные ответа. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php